# Juniper Core and Access Switch best practice

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex

We have Juniper 14x EX4200 as access switches, and 2x EX8208 with virtual chassis configured between the 2 EX8208.

from the access switched EX4200 we need 2 links.. one for the core A and second for core B
since the core switches are considered as one switch (virtual chassis)
what is the best practice here, can i use LACP link aggregation on the core switch and access switches?  or do i need to use RTG Redundant Trunk Groups

Note: im using 10G fiber interfaces

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> can i use LACP link aggregation on the core switch and access switches?

Yes, you can use LACP for exactly the reason you said (the EX8208 is a single logical switch).